# Lock screen bug Ubuntu 20 (Ctrl+Alt+F7)

Tags: 20.04, security, lightdm, unity-greeter

I have discovered a bug in my Ubuntu 20 that I would like to fix, I have searched everywhere but I have not found any solution. The problem is that when I lock the session with the button in the upper right corner if I press "Ctrl+Alt+F7" it returns to my desktop without asking for any password. Does anyone know any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: the package `light-locker` is supposed to prevent this, can you confirm it's installed (should be by default since 16.04 it appears) and set to autostart?

Comment: @Esther HI, yes, I have it installed and still happening, I don't know if I have to configure something. Thanks for the reply.